# Difficult Surface Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surfaces

I am trying to perform a surface integral over kind of a weird shape.  So the radius of the shape should be equal to the multiple of $3$ constants (one for each of the $x, y$ and $z$ directions) each to the power of the magnitude of the component of the unit vector in the corresponding $x, y$ or $z$ direction.  Sorry if this is not too clear but here is the equation:

$$r = \mathrm{x}^{|\cos(\theta)|} \mathrm{y}^{\sin(\theta)|\cos(\phi)|} \mathrm{z}^{\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)}\sin(\theta) $$

Where x, y, z are constants.  So the surface integral should then be:

$$S = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{x}^{2|\cos(\theta)|} \mathrm{y}^{2\sin(\theta)|\cos(\phi)|} \mathrm{z}^{2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)}\sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi  $$

I have been trying for some time to solve this but have not found a successful approach.  Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You say "multiple of $3$ *constants*" -- are $x, y, z$ in your integral constants?

Comment: yes, a,b,c would have been more appropriate I guess but I copied and pasted from my latex code where I used x,y,z to help my thought process.

Comment: This looks like it came from integrating something using spherical coordinates.